# How to use ScrollView inside another layout?

Tags: android, scrollview

I wanted to use ScrollView inside another constraintlayout. But when I put it, all views inside ScrollView disappear. Why, and how to fix it?

**I really appreciate your help and hope you have a nice day!**

my xml

```xml
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".home.profile.PreViewProfileFragment">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        ... />
<ScrollView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/vertical_2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/vertical_98"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/horizontal_10"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/horizontal_98">

        <Another constraintLayout>

</ScrollView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Blueprint like this

[image]

Comment: `android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="true"`  can you try this to the scroll view tag

Comment: thanks so much , i did it. have a nice day , bro!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use like below:

```
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:context=".home.profile.PreViewProfileFragment">
        
            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
                ... />
        <ScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fillViewport="true"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/vertical_2"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/vertical_98"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/horizontal_10"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/horizontal_98">
        
                <Another constraintLayout>
        
        </ScrollView>
        
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```